# Error unterminated string literal when using php javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a file with format

```
<script src="test.php"></script>
```

And code in test.php with table test(id, name) with 4000 rows

```
<?php
$sql = "Select * From test";
$data = array();
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
     $data[] = $row;
}
$str = '';
foreach($data as $row) {
    $str .= $row->name;
}
?>
output('<?php echo $str ?>');
```

When I run code is error is `unterminated string literal`, but when repair code with
`$sql = 'Select * From test order by id limit 100'` is no error, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

Never ever *ever* output PHP values directly.

```
output(<?php echo json_encode($str) ?>);
```

Comment: @OM: It makes sure that the PHP value is converted to a valid JavaScript literal, since all JSON strings are valid JavaScript literals.

Comment: +1 Oh Great can you please suggest me some good learning resource on this?

Comment: ["JSON is a subset of the object literal notation of JavaScript. Since JSON is a subset of JavaScript, it can be used in the language with no muss or fuss."](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the script tag properly it has to be like `</script>`